# using netty as poller and request server ( somekind of network node)

Tags: netty

i need to create network server that polles from DB via in house server API (CORBA) each N seconds using build in clients framework . 
and in response to send http requests to another server.
and catch the response .
can netty be used for such task?

Comment: Yes, Netty can be used for such tasks.

Comment: does it has http client or i need to implement httpclient of my own 
that is using the apache lib?

Comment: It has an http codec included. Please the api docs